# How do I fix a DbProviderServices inheritance error for a MVC3 project on Mono 3.0.3, Entity Framework 6 Beta2 and Npgsql?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, mono, npgsql

I have a MVC3 project targeting .net 4.5 running on Mono to the point where the only thing that is failing is the connection from Entity Framework to PostgreSQL.

I have an almost identical project working in VS 2012 with MVC4, EF6, Postgres.

I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException The 'Instance' member of the Entity
>   Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql' did not return
>   an object that inherits from
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity Framework
>   providers must extend from this class and the 'Instance' member must
>   return the Singleton instance of the provider.

Am I missing something in configuration or is this not going to work?

```
<!--For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468-->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
```

And ...

```
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql">
      </provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Mono ASP.net version string ...

```
Version Information: 3.0.3 (master/39c48d5); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the provider for EF6 and not for EF5? To me the exception looks like you have EF6 project but the provider is EF5 and therefore Instance returns a type that is derived from `System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices` and not from `System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices`. (In EF6 most of the types were moved to a new assembly and new namespaces)

Comment: Pretty sure, I have used the built-in EF that is included with mono and EF6b2 binaries directly referenced. Same result on each.

Comment: Mono has EF6 bits included but EF6 itself does not contain the provider for PostgreSql. The question is where did you take the provider from and whether you are sure it's for EF6 since it looks like it is just for EF5

Comment: Yes that is what I thought but EF6b2/npgsql works in a Visual Studio project without that provider.

Comment: Maybe it's registered in machine.config and therefore you don't see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error.

Change

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql"></provider>
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

TO

```
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: This change makes it connect to MS SQL Server instead of PostgreSQL. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need a PostgreSQL connector for EF6 because of the changes.
you can read more about the situation here:

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the case as well but I have the same or a very similar project in visual studio targeting .net 4.5 and EF6b2 without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change you entityFramework section config to this:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

PS:I using Npgsql version 2.1.0.0

Comment: Thanks, @Garrod Ran got there first.